# Facebook Login Plugin error

Tags: facebook

My members keep get this error when tryng to login.

> Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the Apps domains.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You must change your app domain in Facebook to your website link.
Replace localhost by the URL of your website on internet.

See this image to understand: https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=b24bac03947c1a83&id=B24BAC03947C1A83!11890&sff=1